# Sklearn.PCA-unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, spyder

```
def doPCA(data, dimensions=2):
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
model = PCA(n_components=dimensions, svd_solver='randomized', random_state=7)
model.fit(data)
return model
```

> File "/home/dogus/Downloads/DAT210x-master/Module5/assignment4.py",
>   line 221, in 
>       display_pca = doPCA(T)
>
> File "/home/dogus/Downloads/DAT210x-master/Module5/assignment4.py",
>   line 56, in doPCA
>       model = PCA(n_components=dimensions, svd_solver='randomized', random_state=None)
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'random_state'

- I use Spyder with python2.7 in Ubuntu.
- I installed sklearn with conda,i also installed it via 'pip install'.
- I tried random_state=None but gave me the same error.
- Then i ran it via terminal and it worked without any error.

Edit:

- Scikit-learn(1.18.1),spyder,scipy,numpy,ipython updated via anaconda.
- Then i restarted Spyder and tried to run the code but gave me the
  same error.
- I ran the codes via IPython and Python consoles.

Problem caused by Spyder? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of sklearn. The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) say that the random_state variable was added in version 0.18.0. Try updating sklearn.

In order to make the update, look at these questions

- [How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679938/how-to-upgrade-scikit-learn-package-in-anaconda)
- [conda update scikit-learn (also scipy and numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840496/conda-update-scikit-learn-also-scipy-and-numpy)

---

Based on your comment, just to make sure the problem is not the scikit-learn version, try the following

```
def doPCA(data, dimensions=2): 
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    import sklearn
    print sklearn.__version__
    model = PCA(n_components=dimensions, svd_solver='randomized', random_state=7)
    model.fit(data)
    return model
```

This will only print the version of sklearn being used. As you said that you had also installed sklearn with pip, you could have conflicting versions.

Comment: scikit-learn              0.18.1              np111py27_1

I have updated scikit-learn and spyder via anaconda.Then i restarted Spyder and tried to run the code but gave me the same error.Also scipy and numpy is up to date.

Comment: @Sapientia could you check my edit? It may still be something associated to the version.

Comment: Version is 0.17 Spyder says,good catch.
Do you know how can i fix it? Im searching for it.

Comment: Take a look at the second question I linked. It is about someone who had the same problem as you do now.