# conda update sklearn - does not update

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I am using anaconda python

```
conda --v 
conda 4.3.25
```

I am trying to update sklearn package. I followed instructions from here:
[conda update scikit-learn (also scipy and numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840496/conda-update-scikit-learn-also-scipy-and-numpy). When I try to install the packages, it shows that it is installing sklearn 0.19

```
conda install scikit-learn
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
numpy:        1.13.1-py27_0     
scikit-learn: 0.19.0-np113py27_0
scipy:        0.19.1-np113py27_0
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

However, when I check package version, it still shows 0.15

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
'0.15.2'
```

I further created environment in python.

```
$conda create -n sklearn python=2.7 anaconda
```

it shows below:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
scikit-image:       0.13.0-np112py27_0
scikit-learn:       0.18.1-np112py27_1

source activate sklearn

$python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.15.2'
```

Further, when I looked at packages in pycharm I see both 15.2 and 19.1. Please see attached screenshot. [image]

How to resolve this?
I see that packages get installed in to folder ./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Is this expected with Conda?

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct interpreter (it does not seem like that). Is your anaconda-based python used? For fun: check the version if scipy and compare with 0.19.1.

Comment: >>> scipy.__version__
'0.19.1' >>> numpy.__version__
'1.13.1'  which python /anaconda/bin/python

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH is empty string

Answer (score -1):

I found that there was a conflict of conda package folder with  pip installation folder. I checked for paths using

`import sys`

`print sys.path`

and found that pip installation folder has precedence over conda folder.

Deleting the pip installation folder solved this.

Comment: how did you delete it?

Comment: sys.path will show you the path. Go to directory and delete.